How can I style individual table cells for Markdown to HTML conversion using Pandoc?
In Markdown I have tables like in the following example:
|             | Fruit | Vegetable |
|-------------|-------|-----------|
| Apple       | yes   | no        |
| Broccoli    | no    | yes       |
| Carrot      | no    | yes       |
| Orange      | yes   | no        |
| Tomato      | (yes) | yes       |

Now I would like to highlight the "Tomato-Fruit" cell with some background color when converting the Markdown file to HTML using Pandoc.
I tried adding some cell attribute like this:
| Tomato      | {: .emph} (yes) | yes |

and used the following command for conversion
pandoc -f markdown+markdown_attribute -t html -o output.html input.md

but the HTML output contains the {: .emph} string literally, instead of being transformed into an HTML element class attribute (tested with Pandoc version 3.1.3).
Is there a way to style individual cells in Markdown as parsed by Pandoc?

There's an open issue: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/6317 For now, I'd probably use a native span and put that inside the table cell. Then you can style that.

Thanks for the link. I agree with the point raised therein that at some point one has to switch to using HTML tables, when the simple table syntax gets too complex. Now my workaround is to use ordinary emphasis _(yes)_ in the table cell, and then use a custom CSS to highlight matching cells.
